# Strange MySQL Popup "Mysql Installer is running community mode"

Tags: mysql

I have installed a recent community version of MySQL from MySQL site. The version is `5.6.x`.

It was done using an installer and I also chose the option to create a MySQL service on Windows so that I can simply start the service. The service was set to not start automatically.

Although I am not actively using MySQL, while I am working on my PC on something else, a strange pop-up displays,

> MySQL Running in community mode.

Does something, prints on screen, and closes:

[image: MySql installer]

I am surprised to see this and wonder: what is it doing - connecting to a remote server and doing what? Does someone know the internals and how to prevent it from connecting to a remote server?

Could this be a security issue?

Comment: kudos for being able to get a snap shot of it. If it wasn't for the fact my sql command window has a unique background color I would have never known what it was.

Comment: i ran into it today and it scared me a bit. what a dirty little phone-home feature. i don't remembering agreeing to automatic updates.

Comment: Popped up and made me run through and check every process currently running.... Nasty feature.

Comment: It's running exactly midnight (if your PC is turned on), so it is not that hard to catch. And it pops up for several seconds. But it scared me the first time too. Thought I was hacked...

Comment: @StanE, I think other factors determine when it runs. FE, if your laptop postpones tasks with low battery while unplugged. Mine would run most often at the moment I began charging. Also, the running time is machine and network dependent of course. Mine was an instantaneous flash.

Comment: What's even worse is I never completed my mysql install. I hit cancel after looking at the custom install options, and this spyware still got scheduled on my machine and ran almost 4 hours later! Fortunately, I have a snapshot of the VM before running the installer. Very shady!

Answer (score 531):

Go to *Control Panel* > *System and Security* > *Administrative Tools* and open ***Task Scheduler***.

In the *Task Scheduler* navigate to *Task Scheduler Library* > *MySQL* and select ***Installer***.

From the list at the center of the window right-click ***ManifestUpdate*** and select *Disable*.

[image: Disable MySQL ManifestUpdate]

Answer found [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,626478,626575#msg-626575).

Comment: You should use the MySQL way as stated by @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: I just changed the time from daily `12:00 AM` to `06:30 AM` which I'm sure I'm asleep unlike the midnight! ;)

Comment: The most direct and clear solution. I needed it because I need to safe traffic and unexpected updates on the MySQL.

Comment: Faster way to start Task Scheduler: **1.** press `WIN` + `R` **2.** in poped up window type `Taskschd.msc` and press enter.

Comment: Popping out from ingame while playing cs go, the SQL update was a secure way to lose that round. THX SO MUCH!

Comment: instead of disable it made it weekly or monthly just to keep it securely updated, thanks for the tip anyways!

Comment: How any "professional" product thought this is remotely acceptable blows my mind

Answer (score 303):

Since the other answers require OS interaction I figured it would be beneficial to provide the "MySQL" way.

> I am surprised to see and wonder what is it doing and connecting to a
>   remote server and doing what?

It's keeping the [MySQL Product Catalog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-catalog-dashboard.html#windows-product-catalog) up to date. As described in the documentation,

> This option uses the Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a task named
>   "ManifestUpdate". *(this is the scheduled task that is disabled the OS way)*

> Does someone know the internals and how to prevent it from connecting
>   to a remote server?

To prevent it from connecting you can disable it without going through the OS:

1. Start the MySQL installer
2. Click the wrench image

[image]

3. Uncheck the checkbox to disable automatic updating

[image]

You're ready to go...

> This could be a security issue?

I'm not a security expert but it's connecting to the same people you trusted to get the software from so I think it's more of a nuisance than a risk.

Luckily, you can manually update it as needed by clicking the `Catalog...` button seen above and force it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, always like it to change settings directly in the software instead of changing thing from the os side.

Comment: Thanks. This was such an annoyance... popping up and stealing focus while working or worse, while playing a game. A console really isn't the way to run software updates.

Comment: My MySQL install came with XAMPP and I don't have this GUI so the manual way had to do.

Comment: the most unimportant part of the update process is the most visible and intrusive one? sure, why not... *throwing an ugly look MySQL's way*
good answer, though.

Comment: Thank you; so annoying! Catalog for MySQL is confusing nonetheless. It is needed when you use it to identify objects? Which I haven't found when this is applicable on WIndows OS just yet?

Comment: The Product Catalog link expired.  It looks like they're rewritten the documentation. Hopefully the link I've replaced it with is good enough, but the original can be seen at http://web.archive.org/web/20170116102617/http://dev.mysql.com:80/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-catalog.html

Comment: From security perspective this (fire up a command-line windows then disappear) looks very sneaky, someone needs to tell MySQL to do this another way, or warn user when setting up the first time.

Answer (score 27):

It's just the MySQL update function.

Following these http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/what-is-taskengexe/526f43d3-d311-4637-a19a-a76f1ce351fb you should be able to turn it off:

> 1. Go to the Start menu.
> 2. Type task scheduler and press enter.
> 3. Press continue on the UAC popup.
> 4. In the left pane of task scheduler, underneath Task Scheduler Local, right-click on Task Scheduler Library.
> 5. In the View submenu, make sure the Show Hidden Tasks option is checked.
> 6. Widen the Name column in the center pane. The hidden task that is likely at fault has a name that starts with User_Feed_Synchronization,
>    followed by a dash and a bunch of digits inside a curly brace.
> 7. Select that task in the middle pane by clicking on its name.
> 8. To verify that this scheduled task is creating all those taskeng.exe processes, select the History tab in the middle pane near
>    the middle of the screen. If you expand out the Level and Date and
>    Time Columns, you should see a bunch of errors and date and times that
>    are 5 minutes apart. If that's the case, then this task is the
>    problem.
> 9. On the rightmost pane, select Disable.
> 10. There may be more than one scheduled task like this, so you'd need to disable any or all that were causing problems.
>
> *From an answer by Liza.Z on question "What is taskeng.exe?" on http://answers.microsoft.com/, written April 23, 2013 retrieved Feb. 22, 2016*

Answer (score 19):

It may be better not to completely disable the updater but make it check less often than once a day, which seems over the top. You can not do that without using the Task Scheduler. Double-click the "ManifestUpdate" Name in the Task Scheduler to open the Properties window and select the Triggers tab, here you can use the "Edit..." button to set the task to run as [in]frequently as you like. This is what I have done:

[image: ManifestUpdate Properties]

Be warned that the next MySQL update you do decide to install might undo anything done directly in the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 15):

A lot of answers are suggesting disabling the updater, or having it run less frequently.

If you'd like to keep it running, but not just have the console popping up to intrude on what you're doing, consider running it under another account, or checking the box to run whether or not the current user is logged in. Either of these will make it run silently in the background.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the option to run under another account]