# MySQL Installer is running in Community mode

Tags: mysql

So I installed MySQL couple days ago. Everything is working fine and I love it but there is just one thing. Everyday exactly on midnight this windows pops up.

[image]

I don't know why and what should I do since MySQL works just fine. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but I have this exact same issue with the exact same popup every night. I found [an answer to a similar question from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28068417/16826520), and it seems to be the most reliable method.

Another answer on that thread details a way to disable the installer running automatically through the MySQL UI rather than the task scheduler, but the dashboard seems to have updated since then and that method no longer works.
However, [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/8.0/en/mysql-installer-catalog-dashboard.html#windows-product-dashboard) has instructions for disabling auto-updates in the current version:

> The MySQL Installer Options icon includes the following tabs:
>
> **Product Catalog:** Manages the automatic catalog updates. By default,
> MySQL Installer checks for catalog updates at startup every seven
> days. When new products or product versions are available, MySQL
> Installer adds them to the catalog and then inserts an arrow icon
> next to the version number of installed products listed in the
> dashboard.
>
> Use the product catalog option to enable or disable automatic updates
> and to reset the number of days between automatic catalog downloads.
> At startup, MySQL Installer uses the number of days you set to
> determine whether a download should be attempted. This action is
> repeated during next startup if MySQL Installer encounters an error
> downloading the catalog.

I'm sure your issue has been long resolved, but hopefully my answer will help anyone else that goes searching for a solution to this. :)